# iPhone Reachability - How can I use it across my entire app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, reachability, nsnotificationcenter

I have finally figured out how to use the apple Reachability files, which is a great thing.

My question is, since I have about 6 views, each of which needs to check to see if I am connected to the internet.  What is the best way to implement Reachability (including NSNotificationCenter so I know automatically when the connection has changed) across my app so that I am not copying and pasting the same code inside each class.

I assume something inside my app delegate.  But how would I implement NSNotificationCenter and let all my other classes know when the connection has changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code in whatever view you want notifications for when the reachability changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

You'll want to define the method `- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification* )note` (or whatever you call it) to receive this notification.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I was just wanting to see if that was the way that I should be doing it.  Thanks.